# Haskell: SMTP over SSL

Tags: email, haskell, ssl, smtp

I wanted to write a utility script in Haskell last night that sent some emails using my gmail account.

However, [gmail requires a SSL/TLS connection to their SMTP server](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287), and I couldn't figure out how to accomplish this with [HaskellNet's `sendMail`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaskellNet/latest/doc/html/Network-HaskellNet-SMTP.html#v:sendMail).

How could I have done this with HaskellNet?  Or is there a different SMTP library I should use?

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution?

Comment: Salil: nah, I gave up.  hammar's solution might work.

Comment: There is also some [discussion on Haskell-beginners](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2012-July/010190.html) but it's not a complete solution.

Answer (score 7):

This is quite an old post now, but just thought I'd pop an answer up in case somebody stumbles across it looking for SSL/TLS support for IMAP/SMTP.  I've put a library up on Hackage which adds TLS support to HaskellNet's mail functionality by doing pretty much what [hammar suggested in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8036970/1004609).

You can find the library here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellNet-SSL
along with sample code [here](https://github.com/dpwright/HaskellNet-SSL/blob/master/examples/gmail.hs).

Answer (score 3):

From a quick glance at the docs, I noticed [`connectStream`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaskellNet/latest/doc/html/Network-HaskellNet-SMTP.html#v%3aconnectStream), which lets you use an already-opened stream, as well as the fact that all the functions work on `BSStream s => s` rather than a plain `Handle`. I'm guessing you could use this with the [`tls`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/tls/0.8.2/doc/html/Network-TLS.html) package to write a `BSStream` instance for `TLSCtx a` (or a newtype) to allow you to use a TLS/SSL connection with HaskellNet's `sendMail`.

I don't have any experience with either package, but it looks like it might be possible.

Comment: replace tsl with TLS. TLS is "transport level security". SSL is "secure socket layer"

Comment: I could I guess.  How to use `Network.TLS` for a password-authenticated connection isn't jumping out at me, but I'll stare at it a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [configuring sendmail with GMail](http://appgirl.net/blog/2009/configuring-sendmail-to-relay-through-gmail-smtp/) and using [smtp-mail](https://github.com/jhickner/smtp-mail) to talk to `sendmail`?

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me on `Windows 10`

It uses the hackage [HaskellNet-SSL](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellNet-SSL)

Most of the code is courtesy of [czyzykowski](http://czyzykowski.com/posts/ssl-email-haskell.html)

I need to configure google account to [allow less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) so it's not perfect, but works.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Email where

import           Control.Monad
import           Data.ByteString.Lazy        (toStrict)
import           Data.Text                   (unpack)
import           Network.HaskellNet.Auth
import           Network.HaskellNet.SMTP
import           Network.HaskellNet.SMTP.SSL
import           Network.Mail.Mime

toString :: Address -> String
toString Address { addressEmail = email } = unpack email

defaultMail :: Mail
defaultMail = Mail {
                            mailFrom = Address (Just "My Name" ) "me@example.com",
                            mailTo =[Address (Just "Your Name") "someone@example.com"],
                            mailCc = [],
                            mailBcc = [],
                            mailHeaders = [("Subject", "Haskell Rocks")],
                            mailParts = []
                                                    }
sendEmail msg = do
  rendered   <- renderMail' defaultMail {mailParts = [[plainPart msg]]}
  doSMTPSTARTTLSWithSettings  "smtp.gmail.com" defaultSettingsSMTPSSL{sslPort = 587} $ \connection -> do
      succeeded  <- authenticate LOGIN
                                 "mygoogleaccount@gmail.com"
                                 "mypassword"
                                 connection
      when succeeded $ do
          putStrLn "conntected. Now we'll send the email"
          sendMail (toString (mailFrom defaultMail))
                   (map toString (mailTo defaultMail))
                   (toStrict rendered) connection
```